# SQL check if group containes certain values of given column (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have table audit_log with these records:

```
log_id | request_id | status_id
 1     |  2         |  5
 2     |  2         |  10
 3     |  2         |  20
 4     |  3         |  10
 5     |  3         |  20
```

I would like to know if there exists request_ids having status_id 5 and 10 at the same time. So this query should return request_id = 2 as its column status_id has values 5 and 10 (request_id 3 is omitted because status_id column has only value of 10 without 5).
How could I do this with SQL?
I think I should use group by request_id, but I don't know how to check if group has status_id with values 5 and 10?

Thanks,
mismas

Comment: You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) .

Comment: I am using Oralce db...

Comment: Is the combination `request_id/status_id` unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be a way:

```
/* input data */ 
with yourTable(log_id , request_id , status_id) as (
 select 1   , 2     ,  5 from dual union all
 select 2   , 2     , 10 from dual union all
 select 3   , 2     , 20 from dual union all
 select 4   , 3     , 10 from dual union all
 select 5   , 3     , 20 from dual
 )
/* query */
select request_id
from yourTable
group by request_id
having count( distinct case when status_id in (5,10) then status_id end) = 2
```

How it works:

```
select request_id, 
       case when status_id in (5,10) then status_id end as checkColumn
from yourTable
```

gives

```
REQUEST_ID CHECKCOLUMN
---------- -----------
         2           5
         2          10
         2
         3          10
         3
```

So the condition `count (distinct ...) = 2` does the work

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT   request_id
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY request_id
HAVING   COUNT( CASE status_id WHEN  5 THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND      COUNT( CASE status_id WHEN 10 THEN 1 END ) > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

To check if both values exists (without regard to additional values) you can filter before aggregation:

```
select request_id
from yourTable
where status_id in (5,10)
group by request_id
having count(*) = 2 -- status_id is unique
 -- or 
having count(distinct status_id) = 2 -- status_id exists multiple times
```

Comment: After a lot of searching, you saved my life! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select
    log5.*, log10.status_id
from
    audit_log log5
    join audit_log log10 on log10.request_id = log5.request_id
where
    log5.status_id = 5
    and log10.status_id = 10
order by
    log5.request_id
;
```

Here's the output:

```
+ ----------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------- +
| log_id      | request_id      | status_id      | status_id      |
+ ----------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------- +
| 1           | 2               | 5              | 10             |
+ ----------- + --------------- + -------------- + -------------- +
1 rows
```

And here's the sql to set up the example:

```
create table audit_log (
    log_id int,
    request_id int,
    status_id int
 );

insert into audit_log values (1,2,5);
insert into audit_log values (2,2,10);
insert into audit_log values (3,2,20);
insert into audit_log values (4,3,10);
insert into audit_log values (5,3,20);
```